# Why can’t see the preview of my custom view in storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When the app run in Simulator it works but in Storyboard can’t see the preview, why?

￼[Swift code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23oy4.png)

[Simulator and Storyboard:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ISyi.png)

Can’t see the custom view background color and when drag UIButton object into custom view doesn’t see the real position(x, y) and its background color.

In Android Studio when you add an object (custom view) in layout.xml file you can see the preview automatically, is it possible to do the same thing in Xcode?

Comment: in xcode you can see the preview of those objects (views) which has IBOut reference.

Comment: I think it's beacuse you didn't set the module. just focus module and hit enter.
http://i.imgur.com/CbSGhIs.png?1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR; Call in prepareForInterfaceBuilder**

```
// Call The Custom Setup Here
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    setupView()
}
```

Calling in **layoutSubviews** also works, but is called multiples times in runtime, **prepareForInterfaceBuilder** is called only for Designables Changes, and only with this purpose.

Long Code:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        setupView()
    }

    func InitChildPosition() {
        var i = 1
        for _view in self.subviews {
            if _view is UIButton {
                _view.center.x = (_view.bounds.width / 2)
                _view.center.y = (_view.bounds.height / 2)
            }

            if _view is UIButton && i == 2 {
                _view.center.x = self.bounds.width - (_view.bounds.width / 2)
                _view.center.y = self.bounds.height - (_view.bounds.height / 2)
                _view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            }
            i += 1
        }
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        InitChildPosition()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your `CustomSetup()` from `init(frame:)`

**EDIT**

Interface Builder uses `init(frame:)` to create and position views in storyboards.

Comment: Then I would try what @ocanal suggested: set your module to `Current - CustomView` in the Custom class section of the inspector.

Comment: I set my module and I call my CustomSetup() in init(frame:), nothing changed in my storyboard.

Comment: How about moving your `CustomSetup()` call to `layoutSubviews()`? You'll just need to override the method and don't forget to call `super.layoutSubviews()`.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the subviews of `CustomView` in `CustomSetup()` which is called from the initializer. Your view does not have any button subviews in that case, because subviews can only be added **after** the view has been initialized.

You need to defer calling `CustomSetup()` to a later point, `awakeFromNib()` should work in your case.

Better yet, remove `CustomSetup()` completely and just style your `UIButton`s in the Interface Builder. You will get the same results without all the complexity.